# ¿Como hacer que una aplicacion minimizada se crea que está maximizada y hacerle capturas de pantalla con su HDC?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hardware

Estoy haciendo un programa en c++ que hace capturas de una aplicación cada X tiempo y analiza las imagenes. El problema es que para que pueda hacer las capturas la ventana de la aplicacion siempre tiene que estar mostrando en pantalla la parte que quiero analizar.

Pensé que falsificando una segunda pantalla y maximizando el programa en esa segunda pantalla falsa y haciendole capturas arreglaría el problema pero no he conseguido hacerlo. Además seguro que tiene que haber algun programa que te permita hacerlo y que haga que windows piense que hay dos pantallas.

Sino también a lo mejor existe alguna manera de que una aplicacion se piense que está maximizada y valla pintando en su HDC, consiguiendo su HWND y mandandole mensajes de ventana pero está opción no sé si será posible y es mucho más complicada.

Para los que a lo mejor no entiendan muy bien mi pregunta esto por ejemplo también tiene que servir para compartir el video de una aplicacion por Discord aunque esta no se esté mostrando en pantalla.

Comment: Buen día, podrías intentar con `PrintWindow()` de la librería `<windows.h>` esto funciona aunque la aplicación esté minimizada. Yo creo que es más fácil que maximizar la aplicación en un escritorio virtual

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Esta tarde lo probaré pero si alguien sabe hacer lo de falsificar una segunda pantalla o lo intenta se lo agradezco